# getElementsByName("datepicker[]")[id] jQuery equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is jQuery equivalent for something like this?

```
var date = document.getElementsByName("dateOvr[]")[rowId];
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input type="text" name="dateOvr[]" value=''><span></td>
```

I tried to use something like this:

```
      $( "input[name='[dateOvr]']").datepicker();
```

HTML:

```
  <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input type="text" name="[dateOvr]" value=''><span></td>
```

Doing this date dropdown was displayed after click on every cell in a table, but the value was assigned only to the first one...

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's `rowId` used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$("input[name='dateOvr[]']").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the extra `[]`.

```
$("input[name='dateOvr[]']").datepicker();
```

Answer (score -1):

how about this, that iterates over your elements matching:

```
$( "input[name='[dateOvr]']").each(
  function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
  }
);
```